# how to connect to a server by name instead of IP address?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip-address

I'm trying to make it easier for users in a small office network environment to connect to an office server running Windows Server 2003. Currently, users map network drives using \IP_ADDRESS\DRIVE. What do I need to do to map by server name instead of IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need  some kind of internal DNS service for your network - if you already run Active Directory, you will already have this set up.

If not, you can install the DNS components of Windows Server 2003 (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814591) or you may be able to use your existing office router for internal DNS if it's capable.

Once you have DNS installed and configured and your server's address entered, you can then try to ping the target server from the workstation, of the ping succeeds, you can proceed to add the share mapping.

Comment: I recently configured my DNS with a forward and reverse lookup zones. nslookup returns Default Server: nfs01.nfs01.local. Not sure where to go from here. Ping succeeds if I use ping nfs01.nfs01.local.

Comment: ideally you'd use your organisation name for the domain - i.e. mycompany.local - so your server's FQDN (fully-qualified domain name) would be nfs01.mycompany.local. In any case, you can use the name nfs01 to map your share (your computer will automatically resolve the name to the IP).

Comment: Just tried mapping it from another client but \\nfs01\share_folder returns "Windows cannot access \\nfs01\share_folder" Unfortunately, I'm given a half baked server to work with and I'm still not sure of everything that is/isn't configured :(

Comment: Just a quick sanity-check: is nfs01 the server you're actually trying to share from? You'll also need to check that the DNS server can actually resolve the name (e.g. 'nslookup nfs01' - your 'Default Server' line just tells you which DNS server is being used to try to resolve the query, it's the output below this that you're interested in. See this link for more details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525

Comment: Yes, nfs01 is the server I'm trying to share from. The workstation is a member of the Domain nfs01.local and I have an active directory forest from this domain.

Comment: Use the fully qualified domain name `\\nfs01.nfs01.local\share` instead of just the hostname component.  If you want to use just the hostname component then adjust your DHCP server to push option 015 with a value of `nfs01.local`.